# Evitar que se dupliquen imágenes guardadas en favoritos con javascript

Tags: javascript

Tengo una aplicación tipo tienda en línea que permite al usuario poner en la sección de favoritos los artículos que le hayan gustado, se supone que cada artículo cuenta con una imagen, una breve descripción y su precio, en la parte superior hay un icono de un corazón que es para agregar en favoritos. La idea es que cuando el usuario da click en el corazón, su artículo se guarda en sus favoritos pero el problema es que si le vuelve a dar click al mismo artículo 1, 2, 10 o 100 veces; pues lo guarda en favoritos el número de veces que haya pulsado el corazacito. Cómo puedo evitar que se duplique o multiplique el artículo??? es decir; lo que necesito es que si ya lo guardo una vez y le vuelve a dar click al mismo artículo mil veces, solo debe aparecer una vez en favoritos.

Aquí mi código:

```js
$(function() {

  $('.listing-favorite-icon').click(function() { 
      $favorite_icon = $(this);
      var listing_id = $favorite_icon.data('listing-id');
      var is_favorite = $favorite_icon.hasClass('is-favorite');

      addFavorite(listing_id).done(function(result) {// este es el código para adicionar en favoritos
        $favorite_icon.addClass('is-favorite')
      });
  });

  function addFavorite(listing_id) { // esta es la función para adicionar en favoritos
    return $.ajax("/favorite-listing", { // pero me falta algo para detener que se dupliquen 
      method: "POST",                    // los artículos
      data: {
        listing_id: listing_id
      }
    })
  }
});
```

Pues aquí va:

```js
function FavoriteListings() {
  this.listings = [];
}

FavoriteListings.prototype.isListingFavorited = function(listing) {
  for (var i = 0; i < this.listings.length; i++) {
    if (this.listings[i].listing_id == listing.listing_id) {
      return true;
    }
  }
  return false;
}

FavoriteListings.prototype.addListing = function(listing) {
  this.listings.push(listing);
};

FavoriteListings.prototype.removeListing = function(listing) {

};

FavoriteListings.prototype.getFavorites = function() {
  return this.listings;
}

module.exports = FavoriteListings;
```

Comment: Acá ya no es cuestión que JS se encargue de esa validación completamente. Puedes, a la hora de consultar ese endpoint, validar que ese artículo tenga ese status que mandas a añadir como favorito y si lo está, no agregas nada.

Comment: Me puedes ayudar con un ejemplo o con alguna documentación por favor?

Comment: Edita tu pregunta y agrega la funcionalidad que tienes en el endpoint `/favorite-listing` para poder ayudarte mejor.

Comment: Listo, ya lo añadí